# Ranking players based off the percentages

Tags: php

I have a database that has over 1,000 users and points that rank them on skill. I'm going to take the user with the most points and base off my rankings on that alone. So, say the player has 900 points, I will create 5 "divisions" based off that. The higher the division, the lesser the percentages and harder it is to get into. So, with that being said, let me show you an example.

Here are 5 divisions based from best to least.

- Master
- Platinum
- Gold
- Silver
- Bronze
- Iron

So, the player with the most points would already be in the "Master" division. Then I want to create percentages based off of these divisions. So, for example, here is how I plan on setting up the percentages.

- Master 5%
- Platinum 10%
- Gold 15%
- Silver 20%
- Bronze 25%
- Iron 25%

So as you can see, I need to be able to get the percentages of this and use it on the player who has the most points. So in this case, I need to be able to display this on any user's profile. So I need to take the user's points of the profile I am looking at and compare it with the player who has the most points and form a division for the given player's profile I am looking at.

```
function rank($rank, $mostpoints) {
$count = $rank / $mostpoints;

}
```

I am aware it isn't really much. But I know I can finish the rest off with IF statements, however, I want to know the best way to take percents of this number. I need to be able to take the current rank and spit out a division. I realized, however, that I can't just take the percent of Master (5%) and divide it by the most points and have it allocate as the Master. I need a way to be able to break the mostpoints into 5 sections based on the percentages and then do if statements to see if the user belongs in them based on the rank. Can anyone provide any feedback on the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately we are not a free coding service - although we are more than happy to help you if you get stuck.  Please have a go at coding your solution first. If/when it fails, post your code here and you will surely get help.

Comment: Hey MaggsWeb! You sure do seem experienced. However, I wish you read through my entire question. I didn't ask anyone to code this entirely for me, I asked for the most efficient way to do this. I felt that IF statements are not efficient because it could probably be done with something that can execute it quicker. I asked to find out which way I should go about it that would provide the quicker execute. Thanks though!

Comment: I appreciate the warm welcome though!